# Recording HTTPS mobile calls using Jmeter

Tags: mobile, https, jmeter

I am working on a native mobile application. I am trying to record the mobile events using Jmeter and android device.The calls are HTTPS not HTTP. I read in article that android device doesn't support HTTPS. Is there any other way to record these HTTPS mobile calls using JMeter ?

PS: I imported and installed the ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt on the android device

Regards,
Niroop

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue for iOS devices. You should be able to record HTTP/HTTPS requests. I assume you have updated the proxy server details.

Detailed steps can be found here.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-record-ios-application-http-requests/